# Fail with error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED' when adding liquidity for the first time

Tags: solidity, tokens, pancakeswap

I'm trying to add liquidity for my new token on Pancake Swap.
I'm receiving the following error:

Fail with error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'

I tried adding liquidity via the pancake swap gui without success getting 'JSON RPC ERROR' and without even sending the transaction to MetaMask.
I tried manually adding the liquidity via the PancakeSwap Factory and Router2 smart contracts.
I created the pair address WBNB/SSH with Pancake Factory v2 at the following address:

0x8B562a9417FC155a0264f06eD8E74723f9E8AF5A

The token address is the following:

https://bscscan.com/token/0x7473919d322da77b3966cda85764d57f9b13984b

Smart contract:

https://bscscan.com/address/0x7473919d322da77b3966cda85764d57f9b13984b#code#L1

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT:
Last failed add liquidity:
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xff2366e7f354354824c212346ea1018de0fa378e632dd5c283600dee85bb0379
DATA:
TokenA (mine):0x7473919d322Da77b3966cdA85764d57f9B13984b
TokenB (WBNB):0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c
Amount A desired: 10000000000000 (100'000 tokens)
Amount B desired: 4000000 (0.04 WBNB)
Amount A minimum: Same as desired
Amount B minimum: Same as desired
Timestamp Deadline: 1653511223

Comment: Youve approved the pool contract?

Comment: @BruceDarcy Yes, approved both tokens (WBNB and mine)